# Animate thru various images in Swift - Using customized Load View

Tags: ios, swift, animation, gif, viewdidload

I have a customLoader which I would like to call anytime a user logs in. I want to animate thru all seven photos in gifArray.

```
import UIKit

class CustomLoader: UIView {

static let instance = CustomLoader()
let gifArray: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "beer1")!,UIImage(named: "beer2")!,UIImage(named: "beer3")!,UIImage(named: "beer4")!,UIImage(named: "beer5")!,UIImage(named: "beer6")!,UIImage(named: "beer7")!]

lazy var transparentView:UIView = {
    let transparentView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    transparentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return transparentView
} ()

lazy var gifImage: UIImageView = {
    var gifImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.00, height: 100))
    gifImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    gifImage.center = transparentView.center
    gifImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    return gifImage
} ()



func animate() {
    for image in gifArray {
    gifImage.image = image
    gifImage.animationRepeatCount = 1
    gifImage.startAnimating()
    }
}

func showLoader() {
    self.addSubview(transparentView)
    self.transparentView.addSubview(gifImage)
    self.transparentView.bringSubviewToFront(self.gifImage)
   animate()

}


func hideLoader() {
    self.transparentView.removeFromSuperview()
}
}
```

I call it when the user logs in

```
    In ViewDidLoad:
    CustomLoader.instance.showLoader()
    view.addSubview(CustomLoader.instance.transparentView)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(CustomLoader.instance.transparentView)
```

Problem: It unfortunately just shows the last image. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The for loop here sets the last image

```
for image in gifArray {
```

instead you need

```
gifImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
gifImage.animationImages = gifArray
```

Then

```
func animate() { 
  gifImage.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: How do I change it so it animates with duration.